# Text-align center after floating image

Tags: html, css

I have...

```
div img
{
    float:left;
}
strong
{
    text-align:center;
}


<div>
    <p>
        <img src='image.png'/>
        <strong>Lorem ipsum...</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

Everything is cool, but strong is not aligning center of div, just between free space.
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Align the strong tag horizontally or vertically?

Comment: horizontally ,yes  text-align: center

Comment: I know it, its nice, but it align between free space after image, not all div width..

Comment: You want the strong tag under the image? Please, explain it better.

Comment: i think its impossible to do)

Comment: I think giving text-align:center to div will solve your problem

Comment: in line with image, but strong sholud be align: center of all div)

Comment: I attached a photo..

Comment: Not possible with CSS when using float (AFAIK). Although the image is floated it still takes up space.

Comment: Seperate the title and the content. Like:  `<h3>The Title where you use strong</h3> <div class="content"><img ..><p>Bakka..</p></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your image and your text in separate div tags and applying your styles to those.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imageDiv">
    <img src='http://www.elblogdeyes.com/wp-content/uploads/its-something.jpg'/>
</div>

<div class="textDiv">
    <p>
        <strong>Lorem ipsum...</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.imageDiv{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

div.textDiv {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my holy grails when it comes to centering stuff in css.
Hope it can help you
http://howtocenterincss.com/